# Why is Haskell's 'Generic' class type family 'Rep a' annotated as a type constructor, and not a type?

Tags: haskell

Consider Haskell's `Generic` class :

```
class Generic a where
  -- | Generic representation type
  type Rep a :: * -> *
  -- | Convert from the datatype to its representation
  from  :: a -> (Rep a) x
  -- | Convert from the representation to the datatype
  to    :: (Rep a) x -> a
```

I'm curious as to why it wasn't written as below:

```
class Generic a where
  -- | Generic representation type
  type Rep a :: *
  -- | Convert from the datatype to its representation
  from  :: a -> Rep a
  -- | Convert from the representation to the datatype
  to    :: Rep a -> a
```

More specifically what does the type variable `x` stand for in the standard definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done to allow the `Generic` and `Generic1` classes to share most of their representation types. Whether this was really a good idea is debatable. Just do your best to ignore the extra parameter.